Apply np.expm1 in polars
How to rewrite the pandas function to polars?
I have some problems with np.expm1, there is no such function in polars.
def add_elasticity_predictions(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    data["huber_elasticity"] = np.expm1(data["intercept"] + data["huber_elasticity_coefficient"] *
 np.log1p(data["discount_price"]))
    return data

For example
import polars as pl


data = pl.DataFrame({
    "elasticity_intercept": [-6.195475, -8.437139, -4.741667],
    "elasticity_coefficient": [1.553659, 2.048057, 1.285653],
    "discount_price": [126, 129, 115],
})

the output should be [2.78384188, 3.62672375, 2.93456563]

From https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12891#issuecomment-1841872969:

The numpy function https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html#numpy.expm1
Is a ufunc so you can use it directly such as df.with_columns(np.expm1(pl.col('values')))

data.with_columns(
    (np.expm1(pl.col('elasticity_intercept') 
              + pl.col('elasticity_coefficient') 
              * np.log1p(pl.col('discount_price')))
    ).alias('huber_elasticity')
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ elasticity_intercept ┆ elasticity_coefficient ┆ discount_price ┆ huber_elasticity │
│ ---                  ┆ ---                    ┆ ---            ┆ ---              │
│ f64                  ┆ f64                    ┆ i64            ┆ f64              │
╞══════════════════════╪════════════════════════╪════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ -6.195475            ┆ 1.553659               ┆ 126            ┆ 2.783842         │
│ -8.437139            ┆ 2.048057               ┆ 129            ┆ 3.626724         │
│ -4.741667            ┆ 1.285653               ┆ 115            ┆ 2.934566         │
└──────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────┘


To make this work with Polars, you just need to make a slight modification to your code. Polars does support numpy ufuncs.
def add_elasticity_predictions(data: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    df = data.with_columns(np.expm1(pl.col('elasticity_intercept') + 
                                    pl.col('elasticity_coefficient') * 
                                    np.log1p(pl.col('discount_price'))
                                   )
                             .alias('huber_elasticity')
                          )
    return df

Let's test it out.
pl_data = pl.DataFrame({"elasticity_intercept": [-6.195475, -8.437139, -4.741667],
                        "elasticity_coefficient": [1.553659, 2.048057, 1.285653],
                        "discount_price": [126, 129, 115],
                       })

pl_data = add_elasticity_predictions(pl_data)

Pandas:
0    2.783842
1    3.626724
2    2.934566

Polars:
Series: 'huber_elasticity' [f64]
[
    2.783842
    3.626724
    2.934566
]


In addition to being able to use the numpy ufunc's ability to take an expression as an input, these are also easily implemented functions.
You can do define these functions in the pl.Expr namespace
pl.Expr.log1p = lambda x : (x+1.0).log()
pl.Expr.expm1 = lambda x : x.exp()-1

then you can do
df.with_columns(
    huber_elasticity=(pl.col('elasticity_intercept') 
              + pl.col('elasticity_coefficient') 
              * pl.col('discount_price').log1p()).expm1()
)

OR if you don't like monkey patching you can just do
df.with_columns(
    huber_elasticity=(pl.col('elasticity_intercept') 
              + pl.col('elasticity_coefficient') 
              * (pl.col('discount_price')+1).log()).exp()-1
    
)

In either case you get
shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ elasticity_intercept ┆ elasticity_coefficient ┆ discount_price ┆ huber_elasticity │
│ ---                  ┆ ---                    ┆ ---            ┆ ---              │
│ f64                  ┆ f64                    ┆ i64            ┆ f64              │
╞══════════════════════╪════════════════════════╪════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ -6.195475            ┆ 1.553659               ┆ 126            ┆ 2.783842         │
│ -8.437139            ┆ 2.048057               ┆ 129            ┆ 3.626724         │
│ -4.741667            ┆ 1.285653               ┆ 115            ┆ 2.934566         │
└──────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────┘

